# bot will not log an on_message event

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to get my bot log an automod event, but the bot can not read one line of part of my code. I used prints to find where the problem is and the bot does not read `log_channel = self.bot.guild.get_channel(log_channel[str(message.guild.id)])` this line works for everything else aka my commands but not for the on_message event. My code is below. How can I fix this? Thanks

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):

      curseWord = ['bad words here']
      msg_content = message.content.lower()  

      if any(word in msg_content for word in curseWord):
        if message.channel.type == discord.ChannelType.private:
            return           

        await message.delete()
        embed=discord.Embed(title="No No Word", description=f"{message.author.mention}, Hey! Those words arent allowed here!", color=0x00FFFF)
        author = message.author
        pfp = author.avatar_url
        embed.set_author(name=f"{author}", icon_url=pfp)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        with open('logchannel.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
          log_channel = json.load(fp)

        try:
          if log_channel:
            print("1")
            log_channel = self.bot.guild.get_channel(log_channel[str(message.guild.id)])
            print("2")
            logembed=discord.Embed(title="Bot Log", description="Bad Word Said", color=0x00FFFF)
            logembed.add_field(name="**Message:**", value=f"{msg_content}", inline=False)
            logembed.add_field(name="**Member:**", value=f"{message.author.name}", inline=False)
            author = message.author
            pfp = author.avatar_url
            logembed.set_author(name=f"{author}", icon_url=pfp)
            await log_channel.send(embed=logembed)
          else:
            print('3')
            return
        except (AttributeError, KeyError):
          return
```

My logchannels.json file:

```
{
  "836412234673815590": 845331373392003122,
  "821556171735040020": 821559475210158110,
  "757014581984886856": 793382550948806687
}
```

Comment: what does the variable log_channel usually holds, because I see its the content of a json file

Comment: @EldinAyal What do you mean? Do you mean how log_channel is defined, cause if that is what your asking, its not defined and doesn't need to be.

Comment: so in the output of the program you see the `print("1")` and `print("2")` but the line between is not doing anything?

Comment: yes, i used those to determine where the code was not working when i used the command.

Comment: it does now want to print '2'

Comment: Then the `KeyError` is thrown.. Are you sure the key is in the guild? Also printing the error  instead of suppressing it would help you a lot. `except (AttributeError, KeyError) as exc: print(exc)`

Comment: Ok i will change this and see if this works

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński The log channels id's are in the .json file but im getting a key error. Logging works for everything else. I have the right channel id for logging

Comment: Can you add to your question a snippet of your JSON file?